# How to store user related data in jwt using next auth

Tags: authentication, security, web, next.js, web-development-server

Currently using my middleware I am storing my user I'd and other headers in browser cookie but as it's visible in browser cookie so I want to store that in jwt using next auth as it is encrypted so can anyone please help how to do so ?